# Is it legal to call a destructor on int32_t?

Tags: c++, destructor

I just found out that the following code is not a valid C++ (it doesn't parse at `int` after `~`):

```
int x = 5;
x.~int();
```

However, the following snippet does work:

```cpp
int32_t x = 5;
x.~int32_t();
```

This is because `int32_t` is a `typedef` in my particular implementation of C++, and a destructor can, apparently, be called on any typedef'ed type.

My question is: is any implementation of C++ required to allow the second snipped to compile? In particular, is `int32_t` guaranteed to be a typedef, and is the compiler required to allow a destruction of a typedef if it knows that typedef typedefs something to int?

Comment: Yes. `int32_t` is not a built-in type, and it's not allowed to be a macro.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The C++14 standard draft states `typedef signed integer type int32_t;` as the definition of `int32_t`. As far as I can tell, this does not leave much space for user-defined types and all or even a macro.

Comment: To avoid a close question / open question war, I'm not going to vote to close as a duplicate, BUT ... this is a duplicate of the linked question. Just because that other question doesn't mention `int32_t` doesn't mean that that other question doesn't answer yours.

Comment: @DavidHammen, I lost the link now, but the answer there was explaining why it works for template parameter. It doesn't mean that the same should work for typedefs, or that int32_t must be a typedef to begin with. So it technically was answering neither of my specific questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a clear requirement that `int32_t` be a typedef. We start with [cstdint.syn]/2:

> The header defines all functions, types, and macros the same as 7.18 in the C standard.

So from there we look at the requirement for the C library:

> The **typedef name** intN_t designates a signed integer type with width N, no padding bits, and a two’s complement representation.

[emphasis added]

So yes, `int32_t` must be a "typedef name".

Although (as far as I know) it's never stated directly in normative text, the following note makes it clear that invoking a destructor for a typedef that resolves to a built-in type is intended to compile and succeed ( [class.dtor]/16):

> Note: the notation for explicit call of a destructor can be used for any scalar type name (5.2.4). Allowing this makes it possible to write code without having to know if a destructor exists for a given type. For example,

```
typedef int I;
I* p;
p->I::~I();
```

Comment: The snippet is of course undefined behavior (member access via a wild pointer).  Or does the Standard guarantee that using this syntax on a primitive is a no-op and the member access never actually happens?

Comment: @BenVoigt: Good question. I don't think the pointer should actually be dereferenced, but I'm not sure I can find a statement to say that with certainty.

Comment: "The only eﬀect is the evaluation of the postﬁx-expression before the dot or arrow." (5.2.4)  So then `(*p).I::~I()` bad but `p->I::~I()` good?  And it doesn't actually matter what the type is?  Seems like a defect.

Comment: The only use case of calling destructor explicitly I can think of is to destruct something for constructed by `placement new`, for destruction and deallocation needs to be done separately. As PODs doesn't really do anything on destruction other than deallocating the memory, explicitly calling destructor on PODs should be NOP.

Comment: I think 12.4/13 would apply "The invocation of a destructor is subject to the usual
rules for member functions (9.3); that is, if the object is not of the destructor’s class type and not of a class
derived from the destructor’s class type (including when the destructor is invoked via a null pointer value),
the program has undeﬁned behavior."

Comment: @user3528438: That's not the only use case. One other is switching between elements of a union (now that you can have non-trivial types in a union).

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Although to be fair, switching between elements of a union *also* requires placement new, if non-trivial types are involved.  But the element you're switching from might well have been initialized by a ctor-initializer list or brace-or-equal-initializer, not placement new.

Comment: This is a pseudo-destructor call. The normative specification is in [\[expr.pseudo\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.pseudo).

Comment: @T.C.: Yes, the normative spec of a pseudo-dtor call is there, but I don't see anything there saying the left side of the `.` or `->` must be something like a typedef name or a template parameter.

Comment: @JerryCoffin You mean the right side? That's specified by [the grammar production](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.post#pseudo-destructor-name).